# Помогите написать SQL запрос на вставку данных

Tags: sql

СУБД: MySQL 8.0.29

Есть три таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE userBonuses (
    id INT,
    userId INT,
    bonusId INT
)

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT,
    userId INT
)

CREATE TABLE bonuses (
    id INT,
    ordersCount INT
)
```

Необходимо выбрать все из таблицы `bonuses`. Выбрать ордеры, где поле `bonuses`.`ordersCount` больше чем количество ордеров на пользователя `(COUNT(*) AS order_counts) и GROUP BY userId.`

После чего, необходимо на каждого пользователя создать бонусы в таблице `userBonuses`.

Например, пользователь с ID 10 имеет 3 ордера.

```
INSERT INTO
    `orders` (`id`, `userId`)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (2, 10),
    (3, 10)
```

Правила для начисления бонусов:

```
INSERT INTO
    `bonuses` (`id`, `ordersCount`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 6)
```

- По правилу с ID 1, пользователь должен выполнить 1 ордер, чтобы создать запись в бонус. У нас, пользователь с ID 10 выполнил 3 ордера. На это правило, и на этого пользователя должно быть создано 3 бонуса.
- По правилу с ID 2, пользователь должен выполнить 2 ордера, пользователь с ID 10 получит 1 бонус на это правило.
- По правилу с ID 3, пользователь должен выполнить 6 ордеров, пользователь с ID 10 не получит бонусов за это.

Попытался написать запрос для выборки. Но вот сделать начисление бонусов не могу. Вот сам запрос. Реализует только выборку ордеров.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `bonuses` AS `bonuses`
    ) AS `bp`
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `orders`.`userId`,
            COUNT(*) AS `order_counts`
        FROM
            `orders`
        GROUP BY
            `userId`
    ) AS `or` ON `or`.`order_counts` > `bp`.`ordersCount`
```

[Пример запросов в конструкторе.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5e8cb0dcab1b16b9b6d0bc12dd83a9e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По отдельности:

```sql
WITH 
orders_amount AS (
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) ordersCount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT orders_amount.userId,
       orders_amount.ordersCount,
       bonuses.id bonusId,
       FLOOR(orders_amount.ordersCount / bonuses.ordersCount) bonusesCount
FROM orders_amount
JOIN bonuses ON orders_amount.ordersCount >= bonuses.ordersCount
```

и суммарно:

```sql
WITH 
orders_amount AS (
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) ordersCount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT userId, SUM(FLOOR(orders_amount.ordersCount / bonuses.ordersCount)) bonusesCount
FROM orders_amount
JOIN bonuses ON orders_amount.ordersCount >= bonuses.ordersCount
GROUP BY 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=44891d8c8522ec1d7127e9e3e00a80b0

Для вставки в третью таблицу добавь INSERT и убери лишние поля из списка вывода.

Comment: Простите, а директива `WITH` позволят делать временную таблицу? И как Вы обращаетесь тут `orders_amount.ordersCount / bonuses.ordersCount` к `bonuses`? Я думал, это можно сделать только после ON?

Comment: @Lasna1 *директива WITH позволят делать временную таблицу?* [WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). Это не временная таблица, а временный набор записей. *Я думал, это можно сделать только после ON?* Порядок отдельных операций в тексте запроса и порядок их выполнения - не одно и то же.

Comment: А, например, `userId` 30, правило бонуса 1. Предполагается, что пользователь должен получить 7 бонусов, что верно. С `INSERT` у меня получается, что я создаю одну запись. Можно ли, в зависимости от количества, например, семи, создать, 7 записей. А не одну, с количеством бонусов 7.

Comment: @Lasna1 Можно, но запрос будет длиннее. Только я не понимаю смысла этого мероприятия...

Comment: Структура такая, что бонус рассматривается как один объект. Добавлять в ту таблицу поле, что отображает количество бонуса и решать это на уровне языка программирования не очень хочется. Возможно, у Вас есть пример чего-то подобного? Сам, что-то найти не смог.

Comment: @Lasna Я не понимаю, в чём проблема к первому запросу привязать ещё одну копию таблицы заказов...

Comment: Просто не знаю, как это сделать. Идея в том, чтобы по крону выполнять один запрос, и начислить необходимое количество бонусов всем пользователям. Для чего подправил запрос, чтобы он учитывал уже начисленные. https://pastebin.com/p1pujC2H Но как правильно реализовать вставку - не знаю. Из идей - использовать PHP или NodeJS, но производительность и сам подход очень не нравится.